# How to get Values from EditText in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, functional-programming

I designed and suggestions interface consists of EditText and Button.
So that the user enters a name, address, for example, his proposal. And then pressing the submit button and send an e-mail.

I really need help.
Thank you in advance, and for this wonderful site.

Comment: This my Code: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.guestbook_layout);
etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
etCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_city);
BtSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendReq);
String name = etName.getText().toString();
String city = etCity.getText().toString();
String send = BtSend.getText().toString();
}`

Comment: You got down votes (-5) for your question so I don't want you to get more down votes, thats why I voted to close your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. by using `getText()` method

```
EditText edit_text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextid);

String username=edit_text.getText().toString();
```

Comment: But I want when I click on the submit button, send the information to the e-mail.

I am a beginner :) 'etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
  BtSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendReq);
  
  
  String name = etName.getText().toString();
  
  
  String send = BtSend.getText().toString();'

Comment: @user169734 If you are beginner then show me what you tried till now???

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextid);
String value = text.getText();
```